# IndexVariable objects must be 1-dimensional Error when reprojecting data

Tags: rioxarray

I seem to be having problems with retrojecting data.

```
from xarray import open_dataset
import xarray
import rioxarray

url = "..."
crs = "..."

dataset = open_dataset(url, decode_coords="all")

...
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                  (time: 12, Xc: 400, Yc: 500)
Coordinates:
  * time                     (time) datetime64[ns] 2023-12-19T08:10:00 ... 20...
  * Xc                       (Xc) float32 -7.96e+05 -7.95e+05 ... 8.97e+05
  * Yc                       (Yc) float32 1.125e+06 1.124e+06 ... -1.008e+06
    projection_lambert       int32 ...
    lon                      (Yc, Xc) float32 ...
    lat                      (Yc, Xc) float32 ...
Data variables:
    mosaic_info              int32 ...
    forecast_reference_time  datetime64[ns] ...
    rev_u_displacement       (Yc, Xc) float64 ...
    rev_v_displacement       (Yc, Xc) float64 ...
    precip                   (time, Yc, Xc) float32 ...
...
```

Set the correct crs:

```
dataset = dataset.rio.write_crs(crs, inplace=True)
```

In this set there is precipitation information in 12 time slices. I want to reproject and write to an image file.

I think I can select to correct time slice, like:

```
array = ds.precip.isel(time=1)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                  (Xc: 400, Yc: 500)
Coordinates:
    time                     datetime64[ns] 2023-12-19T08:15:00
  * Xc                       (Xc) float32 -7.96e+05 -7.95e+05 ... 8.97e+05
  * Yc                       (Yc) float32 1.125e+06 1.124e+06 ... -1.008e+06
    projection_lambert       int32 -2147483647
    lon                      (Yc, Xc) float32 ...
    lat                      (Yc, Xc) float32 71.78 71.78 71.79 ... 53.14 53.14
Data variables:
    mosaic_info              int32 -2147483647
    forecast_reference_time  datetime64[ns] 2023-12-19T08:10:00
    rev_u_displacement       (Yc, Xc) float64 -1.507 -1.507 ... -5.472 -5.472
    rev_v_displacement       (Yc, Xc) float64 -2.656 -2.656 ... -7.933 -7.933
    precip                   (Yc, Xc) float32 ...
...
```

Writing to file does work:

```
array.rio.to_raster("/tmp/test1.tif")
```

And this writes a correct image file.

But if I try to re-project first:

```
array.rio.reproject("EPSG:3857")

This gives the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rioxarray/raster_dataset.py", line 121, in reproject
    self._obj[var]
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rioxarray/raster_array.py", line 482, in reproject
    coords=_make_coords(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rioxarray/rioxarray.py", line 166, in _make_coords
    coords = _get_nonspatial_coords(src_data_array)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rioxarray/rioxarray.py", line 144, in _get_nonspatial_coords
    coords[coord] = xarray.IndexVariable(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py", line 2637, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"{type(self).__name__} objects must be 1-dimensional")
ValueError: IndexVariable objects must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: I could not find the answer to solve this issue, however I think I could reproduce it: let's say you define a funtion to create a dataset with geographical information like the one bellow: `create_gis_dataset()` and then you feed it with an affine that does not satisfied the [condition](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/blob/ed75c6578decbbacbd5d8a10890ee408dabd1241/rioxarray/rioxarray.py#L109) `if affine.is_rectilinear and not _affine_has_rotation(affine)` so let's say Affine(1,0.2,0,0,1,0). Then, [_generate_spatial_coords](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/blob/master/rioxarray/rioxarra